# My App freezes when using Hive database in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I initialize and open the Hive database box in my main.dart file and perform the crud operation. App freezes when I reload the app but unfreeze when I remove the "await" keyword behind the Hive.openBox();
*await* **Hive.openBox(ExpenseBoxName);** butthe app will stop performing the database operations.[image]

[image: Main.dart file where I initialize the database and opened the box]

[image: Where the data is supposed to be displayed]

The third snippet is where I performed the crud operation

Comment: add some code snippet to get idea about your issue

Comment: I have done that now.

Answer (score -1):

initialize the database like this

```
void main() async
{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(document.path);
  await Hive.openBox<String>(datbase_name");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: This is not different from what I did in my code.

Comment: did you find any solution yet? such as using isolate or other alternatives?